# Usage of <% symbol in HTML

Tags: html

What does `<%` mean in HTML.?
I have seen such code and can't find what is it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This is not part of HTML, so it doesn't have any use (in HTML). As j08691 points out, this could be part of some template language.

Comment: Yeap. Thanks) I was trying to search it in search panel, but there were no results, so I decided to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a marker for the start of ASP or PHP code depending on the server configuration

Comment: … or JSP or Template Toolkit or one of a host of other languages.

Comment: Yes.you are correct